Can I perform a bit-wise group by and aggregation with Polars `or_`?
Let's say I have an auth field that use bit flags to indicate permissions (example bit-0 means add and bit-1 means delete).
How do I bitwise-OR them together?
import polars as pl

df_in = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "k": ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c"],
        "auth": [1, 3, 1, 0, 0],
    }
)

The dataframe:
df_in: shape: (5, 2)
┌─────┬──────┐
│ k   ┆ auth │
│ --- ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╡
│ a   ┆ 1    │
│ a   ┆ 3    │
│ b   ┆ 1    │
│ b   ┆ 0    │
│ c   ┆ 0    │
└─────┴──────┘

When I group by and sum, things look good, I sum the auth by k
dfsum = df_in.group_by("k").agg(pl.col("auth").sum())

dfsum: shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬──────┐
│ k   ┆ auth │
│ --- ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╡
│ a   ┆ 4    │
│ b   ┆ 1    │
│ c   ┆ 0    │
└─────┴──────┘

So, it looks as if I am using group_by and agg correctly, when using sum.
Not so good when using or_.
dfor = df_in.group_by("k").agg(pl.col("auth").or_())
gives
dfor: shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ k   ┆ auth      │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ str ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ a   ┆ [1, 3]    │
│ b   ┆ [1, 0]    │
│ c   ┆ [0]       │
└─────┴───────────┘

Expectations:
for the or_ I was expecting this result instead:
df_wanted_or: shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬──────┐
│ k   ┆ auth │
│ --- ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╡
│ a   ┆ 3    │
│ b   ┆ 1    │
│ c   ┆ 0    │
└─────┴──────┘

Now, I did find a workaround by using map_batches to call a Python function.  Very simple something like
functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x|y)
but how do I do this without leaving Polars?

ref: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5009

Update.
Bitwise aggregation was implemented in version 1.9.0. So now you can use pl.Expr.bitwise_or():
(
    df_in
    .group_by("k", maintain_order=True)
    .agg(pl.col.auth.bitwise_or())
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬──────┐
│ k   ┆ auth │
│ --- ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╡
│ a   ┆ 3    │
│ b   ┆ 1    │
│ c   ┆ 0    │
└─────┴──────┘

Previous answer. Bitwise aggregation is not yet implemented in polars - issue.
There're a few ways you could approach it though:
1. Pure polars solution.

unique() - not strictly necessary, but can reduce size of the aggregated lists.
list.to_struct() to convert aggregated data to Struct.
.reduce() to apply bitwise or operator.
field() to access all the fields of the Struct within reduce context.

(
    df_in
    .group_by("k")
    .agg(pl.col.auth.unique())
    .with_columns(pl.col.auth.list.to_struct())
    .with_columns(
        auth = pl.reduce(
            lambda acc, x: acc | x,
            exprs = pl.col.auth.struct.field("*")
        ).fill_null(0)
    )
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬──────┐
│ k   ┆ auth │
│ --- ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╡
│ b   ┆ 1    │
│ a   ┆ 3    │
│ c   ┆ 0    │
└─────┴──────┘

2. DuckDB integration with Polars.
You can use DuckDB integration with Polars and bit_or();
duckdb.sql("""
    select
        k,
        bit_or(auth) as auth
    from df_in
    group by
        k
""").pl()

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬──────┐
│ k   ┆ auth │
│ --- ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╡
│ a   ┆ 3    │
│ b   ┆ 1    │
│ c   ┆ 0    │
└─────┴──────┘

3. Polars integration with NumPy
Another possible way to do that would be to use Polars integration with NumPy.
First, use pure polars to aggregate auth columns to lists and convert them to arrays.
df_agg = df_in.group_by("k").agg("auth")

w = df_agg["auth"].list.len().max()

df_agg = (
    df_agg
    .with_columns(
        pl.col.auth.list.concat(
            pl.lit(0).repeat_by(w - pl.col.auth.list.len())
       )
    ).with_columns(pl.col.auth.list.to_array(w))
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬───────────────┐
│ k   ┆ auth          │
│ --- ┆ ---           │
│ str ┆ array[i64, 2] │
╞═════╪═══════════════╡
│ b   ┆ [1, 0]        │
│ a   ┆ [1, 3]        │
│ c   ┆ [0, 0]        │
└─────┴───────────────┘

Now we can get auth column as Series, convert it to 2d numpy array with to_numpy() and use np.bitwise_or and reduce():
(
    df_agg
    .with_columns(
        auth = np.bitwise_or.reduce(df_agg["auth"].to_numpy(), axis=1)
    )
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬──────┐
│ k   ┆ auth │
│ --- ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╡
│ b   ┆ 1    │
│ a   ┆ 3    │
│ c   ┆ 0    │
└─────┴──────┘


I gave duckdb a quick try on the premise that its syntax is easier than jq.  10 mins of CLI errors later, didn't really seem that obvious, at least as a jq replacement and not going to pull it in as an extra dep just for this.  Good to point out that it is an unimplemented feature though, that answers my question well enough.  The specific terms used in the polars or_ doc are somewhat misleading then : Method equivalent of bitwise “or” operator.  Python for example has or and reserves bitwise for |

if you have numpy as dependency already, you can use it instead - see updated answer
